# PHP Doctrine DBAL Schema Autoincrement doesn't work

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm using Silex with Doctrine DBAL. I try to create a table:

```
$schema = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema();
$table = $schema->createTable('admins');
$table->addColumn('id', 'smallint', array('unsigned' => true, 'autoincrement' => true));
$table->addColumn('username', 'string', array('length' => 10));
$table->addColumn('password', 'string', array('length' => 45));
$table->setPrimaryKey(array('id'));
$table->addUniqueIndex(array('username'));

$queries = $schema->toSql(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform());
// or $queries = $schema->toSql(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MysqlPlatform());
foreach ($queries as $query)
{
  echo $query . ";\n";
}
```

This is the output for the MySQL platform:

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
id SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_A2E0150FF85E0677 (username), PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

It's absolutely right ! We can notice the "AUTO_INCREMENT" for the "id" column.

But If I choose the PostgreSQL platform, this is the output:

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_A2E0150FF85E0677 ON admins (username);
```

The auto_increment doesn't work on PostgreSQL platform...
But in the [documentation](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/schema-representation.html#portable-options), "autoincrement" is in the "Portable options" section.
What's the problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [create a sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createsequence.html) manually or use a [serial type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) since AUTO_INCREMENT like magic flag doesn't exist on PostgreSQL platform. It's documented as "portable" because of DBAL can handle this requirement on all platforms, but via different ways.

Try this:

```
$table = $schema->createTable('admins');
$schema->createSequence('admins_seq');
$table->addColumn('id', 'smallint', array('unsigned' => true));
$table->addColumn( ... );
// ...
```

Hope it helps.

**Update** : Ah, after comments i think i figured out what's happening. @Thomas, how and where did you get that `$schema` instance? What is the output of the `get_class($schema)`?

You have to use a [Schema Manager](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html) instance which can be easily grabbed from `$connection` instance and you should issue your commands over that instance for maximum portability.

Example:

```
$sm = $connection->getSchemaManager();
$table = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table('admin');
$id = $table->addColumn('id', 'integer');
$id->setAutoincrement(true); 
$table->addColumn('username', 'string');
$sm->createTable($table);
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank's Foozy but I thought the goal of this kind of library was to hide these differences... The problem is when I create a sequence and I change the platform, for example MySQL, it throws an exception. So, I have to use "if" statements to handle different cases... It's barely better than maintaining a SQL file for each database...

Comment: I never had to add an implicit `->createSequence()` into my schema. Which version of Doctrine DBAL you are using?

Comment: I think using implict createSequence() depends on __construct options of the $schema instance. This quote from latest DBAL reference's Portability section: `Some vendors use sequences for identity generation, some auto-increment approaches. Both are completely different (pre- and post-insert access) and therefore need special handling.` http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/portability.html

Comment: I edited my first post to show the complete code. Foozy, your code raises an exception "Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\AbstractSchemaManager::createTable() must be an
instance of Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table, string given". @StefanoKowalke I use Doctrine DBQL 2.2.*

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad. I just corrected the last example. It should work now.